# Where can I find free 3d models?

Tags: modeling, rendering

I would to know where can I find free 3d models like the following:

[image] cyclette

[image] monitor

[image] piano

My goal is to make a very large render, where these parts are only small details, so I don't need (if I can find a faster way) to learn how to model them by myself. In other words, my render is an "architecture render" and these are only parts to enrich the render.

Some advice? In your opinion, should I learn how to build them or is there a website where I can take and import them to enrich my render?
This question is because I am afraid of spend too much time to model them, when they are only details, not important how they are, I don't know if I am explaining well what I want to say.
Thank you and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: There are some places with free 3d models, like e.g. blendswap.com (other sites have also archives with free models as well)  but you should generally have skills to model them. The free ones might be of not proper quality / not detailed / not constructed as desired etc. See [some of related resources](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15360/1245). That said this question most likely is off-topic here as it isn't about creating anything with Blender.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about that. Should I delete this off-topic question?

Comment: No leave it, it makes it easier to find for future users, making it less likely to happen again.